# How can I get the Search product to my database and send to my datagridview. here is the trick

Tags: c#

If I Search a Product Code from Search_textbox. then the selected product will send to the datagridview. I have my code but it just only searching if that product is in my database table

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("POSSearchProduct",conn);
                    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("_SearchProduct", txtSearch.Text);
                    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dtbl);
                    tblProducts.DataSource = dtbl;
                    tblProducts.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                    tblProducts.Columns[5].Visible = false;
                    tblProducts.Columns[6].Visible = false;
                    tblProducts.Columns[7].Visible = false;
                    adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint after retrieving the DataTable and then check if the _dbtl_ variable contains any rows.

Comment: how can I do that? please help me I'm a newbie in c#

Comment: Start from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019#:~:text=First%20look%20at%20the%20Visual%20Studio%20Debugger%201,Restart%20your%20app%20quickly.%20...%20More%20items...